# hangman program (C language) array issue

Tags: c, arrays

Here is the code I wrote to prepare the hangman game in C language using arrays. It runs but gives me incorrect output. Would love for some fresh eyes to tell me where I may have messed up.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    void Instructions();
    void PlayGame();
    void PrintToLog(char *word);

    int main(char word)
    {
        Instructions();
        PlayGame();
        PrintToLog(word);

        return 0;
        getchar();
    }

    void Instructions()
    {
        printf("This is a game of hangman. Attempt to guess secret word\n");
        printf("by entering a letter from a to z. The game is over once you\n");
        printf("have entered 8 incorrect guesses.\n\n");
    }

    void PlayGame()
    {
        char word[12];
        char guessed[12];
        int i, incorrect_count, found;
        char ch[2];

        strcpy(word, "hello");

        PrintToLog(word);

        for (i = 0; i < strlen(guessed); i++)
        {
            *(guessed + i) = '*';
        }
        incorrect_count = 0;

        while (incorrect_count < 8 && strcmp(guessed, word) != 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(guessed); i++)
                printf("%c ", guessed[i]);
                printf("\n");
                printf("Enter your guess:");
                gets(ch);
                found = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++){
                if (ch[0] == *(word + i))
                {
                    *(guessed + i) = ch[0];
                    found = 1;
                }
            }
            if (found == 0)
                incorrect_count++;
        }

        if (incorrect_count < 8)
        {
            printf("\nThe word is %s. You win!", word);
            getchar();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nThe correct word is %s. You lose!", word);
            getchar();
        }

        return 0;
    }

    void PrintToLog(char *word)
    {
        FILE *pOutput;

        pOutput = fopen("MyLogFile.txt", "w+");
        if (!pOutput) return;
        fprintf(pOutput, "Start of game\n");
        fprintf(pOutput, "This is the word player is trying to guess: %s\n", word);

        fclose(pOutput);
    }
```

The incorrect output I get is:

This is a game of hangman. Attempt to guess secret word by entering a letter from a to z. The game is over once you have entered 8 incorrect guesses.

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: k

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: l

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: u

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: h

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: e

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: o

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: k

"* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *"

Enter your guess: l

The correct word is *****. You lose!

THERE SHOULD only be (5) * * * * * above the guess line for each letter of the word "hello" that is being guessed, but instead 25 * show up. And then on the very last line it should say "The correct word is hello. You lose!" but it doesn't as something is wrong in my program and I can't figure it out. I created a pointer version of the program and it works just fine. But I cannot find where I went wrong on this version.

Comment: `*(guessed + i)` stop doing this. Write `guessed[i]`.

Comment: Never ever use gets.

Comment: What's the point of having `getchar();` after a `return` statement?

Comment: Enable the highest level of warning for your compiler, and don't even try to run your program until it compiles with no warnings.

Comment: `main (char word)` is not a good idea.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(guessed); i++)` is wrong, `guessed` is uninitialised at this point.

Comment: You don't null-terminate `guessed`.

Comment: You never check that all the letters are guessed correctly.

Comment: @n.m correctly identifies a number of issues.  I'll explain how they produce your output.  Presuming you're on a platform where the stack grows downward, `guessed` is allocated at a lower address than `word`.   In your `for` loop that determines how many asterisks to write into `guessed`, you take `strlen(guessed)`.  But `guessed` is uninitialized, and `strlen` determines the length of a string by looking for a `'\0'` at the end.  In your case, `guessed` contains no `'\0'`, so it keeps scanning into higher addresses, and finds the `'\0'` at the end of `word`.  Hence, it overwrites both w/`*`s.

Comment: As for why that yields 25 `*`s, it must be that there are 8 bytes of padding between `guessed` and `word` on the stack.

Comment: babon, our teacher always has us use getchar in our main function with the return 0 so that it leaves the output window open in visual studio.

Comment: I found the problem a few hours after I posted this. The problem is like n.m. stated. Once I changed  *(guessed + i) to guessed[i] and *(word + i) to word[i] it fixed most of the problems, with some other minor changes. But now it is working as intended. I appreciate you n.m. and @lockcmpxchg8b for your help! It helps clear up what was going wrong.